# Issues with Gitlab-shell installing GitLab6 on SLES11.2

Tags: git, apache, shell, gitlab, suse

I tried to install **GitLab6** on **SUSE Enterprise 11.2** following this guide: https://github.com/n3rdbeere/Installation-guide-for-GitLab6-on-SLES11/blob/master/README.md

The installation has been performed on a private local server that has already the apache2 http server running, so I didn't install the nginx server (as from the end of the above linked guide). Furthermore, because of company's reasons, I had to install all the gitlab stuff on /appl/git/ instead of /home/git/ (obviously, I've created the git user as written in the linked guide).

My problem is that although gitlab-shell seems to be correctly installed, the gitlab check fails. Going step by step, if I run as git user:

```
./<gitlab-shell-dir>/bin/check
```

I get:

```
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files:
        /appl/git/repositories: OK
        /appl/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
```

If I run as git user from the :

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get:

```
System information
System:         SUSE LINUX 11
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p247
Gem Version:    2.4.1
Bundler Version:1.7.2
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:        6.1.0
Revision:       a129bce
Directory:      /appl/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084
HTTP Clone URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        1.7.1
Repositories:   /appl/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /appl/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

I have obviously replaced my private host for privacy reasons. As you can see I have configured my service to be run (and unicorn to listen on) the port 8084 instead of the default 8080.

**BUT**, when I run as git user from the :

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get:

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.1 ? ... FAIL. Please update gitlab-shell to 1.7.1 from Unknown
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ...
Administrator / Test ... repository is empty

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  Redownload the init script
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
projects have namespace: ...
Administrator / Test ... yes
Projects have satellites? ...
Administrator / Test ... can't create, repository is empty
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.12)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

The so called "Administrator/Test" is a test project that I've created within the Gitlab UI: in fact, although the errors in the last check, I am able to remotely access the Gitlab server, creating user, projects and so on, **BUT I am unable to push anything** . I think the problem depends on that gitlab-shell failed checks, but I wasn't able to figure out why!

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you try and update to latest gitlab 7.2 with latest gitlab-shell, or is this not an option? This update guide should work https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/6.0-to-7.2.md

Comment: Hi axil, thanks for your useful link. Updating might be an option, but I'd rather understand what's wrong with my current installation first, so to be prepared facing a same problem when (eventually) upgrading to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm gitlab 6.2 runs on SLES 11 SP 3. You need to edit the init-Script though because it makes some ubuntu-style assumptions. Otherwise the REDIS server won't start correctly.

Also make sure you have a recent version of git from the Open Build Service - the version shipped with SLES is too old.

Comment: Hi, I ended up deleting everything out and re-installing from the beginning. Following your suggestion,I installed Gitlab 6.2 even if I was still running SLES 11 SP2. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-2-stable/doc/install/installation.md), of course with SLES commands instead of Ubuntu ones (keeping the original [6.1 guide](https://github.com/n3rdbeere/Installation-guide-for-GitLab6-on-SLES11/blob/master/README.md) in mind). Removed every installation of ruby and put the 2.0.0p481 on, with gem 2.0.14. Ruby 1.9.1 used to give me problems with _libyaml_ ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I deploy gitlab on openSUSE 12.2/12.3 for many times now.
I would suggest to try with Gitlab 6.9.2 and gitlab shell 1.9.3

Comment: Hi, I need to install Gitlab on a SUSE Enterprise 11.2 server with very strict limits in library/dependencies/modules installation and upgrade. For instance, the currently installed ruby version is 1.8.7 !! And the company repository doesn't have any more recent release available and installable from zypper or yast.